# How do I mock 'open' when I'm using it as a context manager, and iterating over the file pointer?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm using Python V3.6.1 on Windows. The examples below fail in pytest. These are the solutions I found but they don't work here. I can't change the code to use readline.
The first test fails with `"AttributeError: __enter__"`. The second test fails the assert with an empty 'buf'
I found a bug discussion that says mock_open was fixed in 3.7, but that doesn't help me here.

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import Mock, MagicMock, mock_open, patch

def read_withfor( fn):
  buf = []
  with open( fn, 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
      buf.append( line)
  return buf

text_str = 'test1\ntest2\ntest3\n'
text_list = [ 'test1\n', 'test2\n', 'test3\n']

def test_read_withfor1():
  mock = MagicMock( name= 'open', spec= open)
  mock.return_value = iter( text_list)
  with patch( 'builtins.open', mock):
    buf = read_withfor( 'test.txt')
    assert buf == text_list

def test_read_withfor2():
  mock = mock_open( read_data= text_str)
  with patch( 'builtins.open', mock):
    buf = read_withfor( 'test.txt')
    assert buf == text_list
```

**UPDATE**

I mocked a context manager and verified that it worked using the commented code. BUT, when I applied the mock to the test above, I got `"AttributeError: __enter__"` again:

```
def se_enter():
  print( "Entering . . .")
  return iter( text_list)
def se_exit( exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
  print( "Exiting . . . ")
  pass

contextmgr = Mock()
contextmgr.__enter__ = Mock( side_effect= se_enter)
contextmgr.__exit__ = Mock( side_effect= se_exit, return_value= False)

# print( "Starting")
# with contextmgr as cm:
#   print( contextmgr)
#   print( cm)
#   print( "Middle")
#   for i in cm:
#     print( i)
# print( "Ending")
```

Comment: Test1 fails because the mock is incomplete, the `__enter__` & `__exit__` methods need to be mocked as well. However Test2 works properly for me

Comment: The [`mock_open` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.mock_open) suggest that iteration didn't work until 3.8.

Comment: For test 1, I expected the spec to do the mocking. And it blocks `__enter__` & `__exit__` from being added as attribute. For test 2, mock_open is supposed to work for V3.7 and above. I don't have that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean "spec blocks adding `__enter__`". The first test works fine for me in both 3.6 and 3.7 if I add `__enter__` (e.g. `mock.return_value.__enter__.return_value = iter(text_list)`)